# load image from sqlite db and display

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a sqlite db and like to load an image out of it and show it on site.
Unfortunately, once I echo the image (which works) nothing else will be shown. So I guess I am missing something here.

That's my code:

get_image.php

```
<?php
  function get_icon($id){
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:rdb.db3');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM icons WHERE _id = " . $id;
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $result["bytes"];
  } 
?>
```

show.php

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors',"1");
  require_once 'get_image.php';
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $icon = get_icon($id);
?>
<p>Show further content...</p>
```

Anyone who could possibly help me out here?

Thanks in advance! :)

Andreas

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to inspect the pages and look for errors. If you comment out the call to `get_icon()` does anything change? What steps have you taken to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php script is echoing out an image but you probably want to echo out html that includes the image.

To do that, you can set the script as the source of an image in your html:

```
<img src="get_image.php?id=XXX">
```

Note that you would have to move the code that handles the id from `show.php` to the `get_image.php` script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `<img/>`-*tag* which refers to a URL/path that then returns the image. Something like

```
<img src="/get_image.php?id=xxx"/>
```

Comment: @AndreasB if this solves your problem, please mark the answer as solution.